# Ommiting short-term position and background check

Tags: united-kingdom, background-check

I have recently been lucky to get a job offer and I have been advised that once  I will pass the background check I can start working.
I wonder about one thing as I didn't put one short-term position on my CV which lasted 1-2 months. I didn't lie on my CV so that short gap of about 2-3 months is visible. I have never been asked any question regarding this.

When I was completing the background check application I did put details of this position so the gap can be explained.

My question is whether my employer can not employ me once he will realize I had a short-term position that I didn't mention? I feel anxious about this check and I don't know whether I should send HR an email now explaining or wait for results?

Comment: What general industry is this in?

Comment: That would be for a bank Institute.

Comment: Hi Joe, it was part-time position and I didn't feel like I was a good fit. Company enviroment wasn't for me and I decided to find something different and full time. I thought that experience is not relevant as I didn;t learn much so talking about it during interview wouldn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether the employer can revoke my offer once he realizes I had a short-term position that I didn't mention?

You didn't mention a country, or if this was an official offer etc... but in general:

It sounds like you haven't actually (officially) been offered the job yet. So yes, the employer probably could turn around and decide not to employ you, and can do this for any other reason so long as it's not discrimination.

> When I was completing the background check application I did put details of this position so the gap can be explained.

Is it a CV or resume. They have different meanings, or the same depending on country. Usually on a CV you would be expected to include it, but not on a resume.

It sounds like you provided a resume, and as you provided details on it when you completed the background check application, you have provided all the detail required.

So personally I don't think you need to contact HR and explain it however, if you want to, I don't think it will cause any harm.

Comment: Hi ! I applied in UK so as I am aware it's not required to include every single job I had.I don't  want them to think that I lied as I didn't.

Comment: Yeah, in the UK it's always referred to as a CV, but in the UK a CV is often provided more like a resume b/c no one has time to read a full traditional CV. So in the UK it's not expected that your CV includes every detail. -- So as it's UK and you included it when you filled out a background check, I would not see that as dishonest.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion ! I want to be upront with them anyways, but I am not that experience to know how that migh be seen by them. Your opinion is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you're from the UK so my answer is based on that:

Your CV is about showing your relivent work experience, not about giving them a play-by-play of everything you've done over the past 10 years. Missing out a 1-2 month position is not a big deal and nothing to worry about.

Be prepared as they may ask your for a reference for this job, but (as you mentioned) you've already declared it on the back ground check application, which is exactly what that application is for!

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I was not sure about it as I am not experienced with UK process, so I don't want to be perceived as a liar by omitting something.